# Png with alpha background

Tags: php, png, gd, opacity

I'm trying to create a URL, that spits back a 1x1px png with a certain alpha value e.g. `www.mysite/com/png.php?alpha=50` which will output a 1x1 png, with the background colour set to black, and having the opacity at 50%.

I've searched through lots of tutorials and posts trying to figure out how to do this, but I can't find anything that works. Is this possible to do with PHP alone?

Here's the closest I've gotten

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png'); 
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(500, 300);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
$black = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 255, 255, 255, 50);

imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 500, 300, $black);

// Save the image
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

However, that seems to overlay a 50% black colour on top of a white background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the white to transparent, by adding these lines after `$black = ...`

`$colourWhite = imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255);
imagecolortransparent($im,$colourWhite);`

Comment: How would I specify a certain alpha value with that function?

Comment: Hi. I've taken just the key part of the function I originally quoted and given you lines that should replace the unwanted white with a wholly transparent background. You then add the alpha in the way you are already doing successfully.

Comment: (Obviously you also need to use a cleansed version of $_GET['alpha'] in place of the 50 to achieve your goal.)

Comment: A bit of playing around I got it sorted, thanks for your help :)